# How to use Android Annotations and its annotation processor with jack?

Tags: android, gradle, android-annotations, annotation-processing, jack

Does anybody know how to use Android Annotations with the jack compiler ?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/frlgrd/5e890bc0725ebf657b3e318dddcf998f) my app/build.gradle and [here](https://gist.github.com/frlgrd/55bcac03e98c9da78efe1f335d3f243e) my project build.gradle

With this configuration, I have this error message when I build my project :

```
Error:Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the `android-apt` plugin and the `apt` block completely, because it does not work with Jack annotation processing. Also, you have to declare processsors in the `annotationProcessor` configuration. Lastly, you have to add the annotation processing parameters to jack ([which has no public API per-variant, yet](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210753)).

Here is your modified *build.gradle*:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frlgrd.streamzone"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

// Android Annotations
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'

dependencies {

    // Google
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

    // Android Annotations
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    // RX
    compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.1@aar'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
}

// add annotation processing options to jack
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions
            .arguments = ['androidManifestFile': variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile?.absolutePath]
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me (`compileSdkVersion 25`, `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'`, `targetSdkVersion 23`, `AAVersion = '4.2.0'`)

Comment: @WonderCsabo the compiler tells class `SomeClass_` not found which means AA's annotation processor is not processed so the generated class not found.

Comment: Can you open a new question with your problem?